# How to use delay function in C on Ubuntu

Tags: c

I used delay function in Turbo C/C++ in Windows and it worked well.

Now my problem is: I want to run the delay function in Ubuntu but it showing the following error:

```
pass.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `delay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now the header file in Windows was `dos.h` which is not available in Ubuntu! So is there any different header file or is there no function named `delay` supported in Ubuntu? If so then please give me any other example rather than `delay`.

Comment: `dos.h` is not a Windows header -- as its name states. It's way older than that (and also, possibly unique for the *ancient* Borland Turbo C compiler). +1 to negate the (largely unjustified) downvote and for trying to break free of Old Man Troubl-o C; you might want to investigate what functions and libraries are "standard" for most current compilers.

Answer (score 4):

There is a function called [sleep](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html) for a delay in seconds.
Another function called [nanosleep](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html) for intervals specified in nanoseconds.

Comment: Since `sleep` and `nanosleep` are defined by POSIX they should work on all compliant systems, not just with GCC in Ubuntu. The Windows API has [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx).